# ListView that take inputs from a dialog window

Tags: android

I am creating a android project that contains a `ListView` which needs to get input from the
`dialog window`.I had heard about the `notifydatachanged` method but i have no idea of how to
do it could anyone help me.

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer of what you want to do.  notifyDataSetChanged is an Adaptor function that tells it that data has been changed in the listview and it needs to redraw.

Answer (score 0):

take the input from the dialog window and add it in an array list then call the array adapter to add the list items and if the contents of the listview are to be changed then after taking input from dialog call `notifydatachanged()` it will automatically refresh the list